# Scraping Aliexpress using cheerio node

Tags: node.js

I want to **scrape** product title on AliExpress.com but everytime i run the code, it returns null. this code works fine for other sites but having problem with AliExpress

tried using cheerlo as in the code

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const url = 'https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32802143342.html?spm=2114.search0204.3.1.4abe62edEDKF3m&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0%2Csearchweb201602_8_10065_10068_319_10059_10884_317_10887_10696_321_322_10084_453_10083_454_10103_10618_10307_537_536%2Csearchweb201603_52%2CppcSwitch_0&algo_expid=22677928-1324-4b99-a460-9c80cea25c1e-0&algo_pvid=22677928-1324-4b99-a460-9c80cea25c1e&transAbTest=ae803_4';
request(url,(error,response,html) => {
  if(!error && response.statusCode == 200 ){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const title = $('.product-title');

    console.log(title.html());
  }
});

expected: product title html

actual: null
```

Comment: In the HTML response, there is no element that has `product-title` class.

Comment: Thank you for replying @shaochuancs, if you open the url, you can see 'product-title' class. i screenshot it at https://ibb.co/jvqW5Wj

Comment: However, in the HTML response body, there is no "product-title". It seems this element is composed dynamically by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

use `puppeteer` instead of request, with puppeteer we can get data that come also from javascript, with request you got just data that come before js has been loaded

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Do you mean use puppeteer instead of cheerio? request is for making http calls which is not at all similar to what puppeteer does.